# Create dynamic folders and sub folders inside blob via Azure dynamic expression

Tags: azure, kotlin, azure-data-factory

I wanted to create folders and subfolders inside my container per this way inside the copyActivity. Everytime i run this i wanted the pipeline to create new folders per the date in the landing container.

***size/oracle/finance/ddmmyyyy/ddmmyyyyhhmmss/file.csv***

Here are the dataset variables that i declared.

`landing conatiner = size`

`directory = /oracle/finance/`

`filename = @concat('/oracle/finance/', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'ddmmyyyy'), '/', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd-HHmmss'), '/hey_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'ddmmyyyyhhmmss'), '.csv')`

The adf dynamic expression is not producing the right results. I wanted the expression to create datestamp folder and a subfolder inside it with date time stamp and a csv file inside it.

what i tried

`@concat('/oracle/finance/', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd'), '/', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd-HHmmss'), '/hey_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd-HHmmss'), '.csv')`

what i was expecting

***size/oracle/finance/ddmmyyyy/ddmmyyyyhhmmss/finance.csv
size/oracle/account/ddmmyyyy/ddmmyyyyhhmmss/account.csv***

Every time the activity runs, it should create separate folders and sub folders based on time inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **to create datestamp folder and a subfolder inside it with date time stamp and a csv file inside it.** you need to pass the values like

```
landing container = size
directory = oracle/finance/
filename = @concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'ddMMyyyy'), '/', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), '/hey_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'ddMMyyyyhhmmss'), '.csv')
```

**There is no need to again include directory in file name** see below reference:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]